# Consider $P(A_i) = 1,\,\forall i \in \mathbb{N}.$ Prove that $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = 1.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been working on some tough problems in my statistics book, and I came
across a problem that I was having some difficulty with. Consider
$$ P(A_i) = 1,\,\forall i \in \mathbb{N}.$$
I want to prove that
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = 1.$$
I can see where the intuition comes in here, but it is difficult for me to
entirely see it. I had imagined initially that I could simply create a massive
conditional chain, i.e.
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i | \bigcap_{i=2}^{\infty} A_i\right)
P\left(\bigcap_{i=2}^{\infty} A_i | \bigcap_{i=3}^{\infty} A_i\right) ...
=P\left( A_1 | \bigcap_{i=2}^{\infty} A_i\right)
P\left(A_2 | \bigcap_{i=3}^{\infty} A_i\right) ...,$$
However, I am not sure what I should do to properly calculate these,
nor am I entirely sure if this was logically reasonable in terms of the
definitions of probability. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do we know more about $A_i$'s? For example, if $A_i$'s are disjoint this can not be true.

Comment: @Boby If they are disjoint, then the initial assumption does not hold, so no need to prove anything.

Comment: The sets can be disjoint if the disjointness is due to differences on a set with zero probability. For example, defining a non-atomic probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A_i=\mathbb{R} - \{q_i \}$ with  $\{q_i \}_{i}$ an enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: @Pipicito But $\mathbb{R}-q_1$ is not disjoint from $\mathbb{R}-q_2.$ I agree in this case that the intersection of the whole collection is empty though.

Comment: @coffeemath You are right. My fault :) But the intersection of the whole collection is not empty, is $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Pipicito Yes, that's what I found a bit later after making that comment, that the irrationals make up the intersection. And that intersection has full measure (measure 1 if one is restricting to e.g. $[0,1]$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $P( (\cap_i A_i)^C) = P( \cup_i A_i^C) \leq \sum_i P(A_i^C) = \sum_i (1-P(A_i)) = \sum_i (1-1) = 0$.

Comment: That's pretty much a full solution!

Comment: Yeah. You'd write it up with a bit more fluff for a homework assignment though (e.g. say the first step is De morgan's, second step is subadditivity of measure, third is a probability property, etc.), then finally use non-negativity of probability to conclude prob of complement is equal to zero. Then, use step 3 again to finish the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F,P)$ be the probability space. Another way to do this is by noting that two events, $A,B \in \mathscr F$ are equivalent if $P(A \triangle B)=0$ and if $A^*=\{B \in \mathscr F: P(A \triangle B)=0\}$ then $P(B)=P(A)$ for every $B \in A^*$.

So we want to show that $\cap_n A_n$ is equivalent to $\Omega$ since this would mean $P(\Omega) =1 =P(\cap_nA_n)$

$P(\cap_nA_n \triangle \Omega)= P(\cap_nA_n \setminus \Omega)+P(\Omega \setminus \cap_nA_n) = P(\Omega \setminus \cap_nA_n)=P(\Omega \cap \cup_nA_n^c)=P(\cup_nA_n^c)\le\sum_nP(A_n^c)=0$

$\Rightarrow P(\cap_nA_n \triangle \Omega)=0$

$\Rightarrow P(\cap_nA_n)=P(\Omega)=1$