# If $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i \in N$, show that $P(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm stuck at this probability theory question.

Having some troubles in proving this question and need some help or guidance:

> If $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i \in N$, show that $P(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)=1.$

Comment: Pass to complements and use De Morgan's laws.

Comment: It is done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816366

Answer (score 0):

Bonferroni's Inequality states that:
$$P\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_n\Big)\ge\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - (n-1)$$

Let $B_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$, then by Bonferroni and the fact $P(A_i) = 1\ \forall i$, $P(B_n)\ge 1$, but $B_n$ is a decreasing sequence, so using continuity property of probability we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(B_n) = P\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_n\Big)\ge 1$$
Since $P(Any\  event)\le 1$, the result follows.