# A proposal proof for $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)=1$

Tags: probability

This is a follow up to the question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816366/consider-pa-i-1-forall-i-in-mathbbn-prove-that-p-left-bigcap-i).

I'd like to know if the following proof works as well:

Since $P(A_i)=1=P(\Omega)$. Then $\forall i\geq 1$
$$P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) = P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \Omega \right) = P(\Omega) = 1$$

Comment: Just because two events have the same probability, it doesn't mean you can replace one event with another like this. The probability of the intersection might be different.

Comment: Let $A_i$ be the event of rolling a die and getting $1\le i\le 6$. Notice $P(A_1\cap A_1)\ne P(A_1\cap A_2)$, even though $P(A_1)=P(A_2)$. As Mark notes, equiprobable events are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Mark What I meant with the replacement was to say that the event $A_i$ is the sample space $\Omega$. But as coiso pointed out that may not necessarily be the case! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mark and @coiso, it is important to note that $P(A_i) = 1 = P(\Omega)$ does not mean that $A_i = \Omega$ (That the events are the same).